# How to add *.yml files from the third party libraries to the include argument (-H:IncludeResources) while compiling spring-boot application i?

Tags: java, spring-boot, native, graalvm

I have used this in my pom.xml

```
<buildArgs>
       <buildArg>-H:IncludeResources=".*yml$"</buildArg> 
</buildArgs>
```

But still I am getting the exception while running the native executable

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument "src" is null
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._assertNotNull(ObjectMapper.java:4980) ~[2.15.2]
at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3824) ~[2.15.2]
at io.github.mngsk.devicedetector.device.AbstractDeviceParser.(AbstractDeviceParser.java:32)